# Is there a way around this without using Vuex?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I'm building an SPA with Laravel, Vue js and Vuex.
In AppSidebar.vue, I'm using an if statement that basically says if the employer profile exists, show the link for the "View Profile" page, if it doesn't exist show the link for the "Create Profile" page.

AppSidebar.vue:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
    <template v-if="!this.employerProfiles">
        <li class="nav-item"><router-link class="nav-link" to="/employer/profile/create">Create Profile</router-link></li>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <li class="nav-item"><router-link class="nav-link" to="/employer/profile">View Profile</router-link></li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

This is my Async function that gets the data:

```
import * as employerProfileService from '../services/employer_profile_service.js';

export default {
    name: "employerSidebarNav",

    data() {
        return {
            employerProfiles: []
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.loadEmployerProfile();
    },

    methods: {

        loadEmployerProfile: async function() {
            try {
                const response = await employerProfileService.loadEmployerProfile();
                this.employerProfiles = response.data.employerProfiles

            } catch (error) {
                this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
            }
        },
    }
}
```

My problem is after the Employer creates a profile, they get redirected to a page where they can view and edit their profile, it still says "Create Profile" in AppSidebar.vue, instead of "View Profile". If I refresh the page, only then does it say "View Profile".

Is there away around this WITHOUT having to create a Vuex Store for this and use state?
I created a store for my authentication, for now, I haven't used Vuex for anything else in my application. In a few months, I will most likely use Vuex for everything in my application but right now, everything is working well, my client and I are both ready to deploy and this is my only little bug left.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried computed? For example, instead of v-if, v-else you will have only one <li> and at Create Profile/View Profile you replace it with computed attribute {{ profileText }}. Inside profileText() computed you write your logic to display the right text.

Comment: Is profileText() inside computed a function? Do I write it like this?
computed() {
            profileText() {
                Logic here
            }
        },

Comment: almost there. computed: { profileText() { ... } }, Please read more on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: So the computed functions I created for profileText and profileURL are working, but again only if you refresh the page manually. After I submit the Create Form, it still says "Create Profile".

Comment: profileText: function () {
                if(!this.employerProfiles) {
                    return 'Create Profile'
                } else {
                    return 'View Profile'
                }
            },

            profileURL: function () {
                if(!this.employerProfiles) {
                    return '/employer/profile/create'
                } else {
                    return '/employer/profile'
                }
            }

Comment: Have you checked in VueDevTool whether variable employerProfiles has changed? It should work... You might wanna check for its length instead. if(!this.employerProfiles.length)

Comment: Your right employerProfiles remains empty, it only loads the data after the page is manually refreshed. Strange, I created my async function and I thought that calling the function in the mounted hook would load it automatically every time there is new data...

Comment: methods: {

            loadEmployerProfile: async function() {
                try {
                    const response = await employerProfileService.loadEmployerProfile();
                    this.employerProfiles = response.data.employerProfiles

                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
                }
            },
        }

Comment: mounted() {
            this.loadEmployerProfile();
        },

Comment: not really, mounted() only gets called once at the beginning. You will need other events to reload the data.

Comment: How can I pass data down from one component to another? I tried adding the loadEmployerProfile function inside my ProfileCreate.vue file and then calling that function inside my createEmployerProfile method.
loadEmployerProfile: async function() {
                try {
                    const response = await employerProfileService.loadEmployerProfile();
                    this.employerProfiles = response.data.employerProfiles

                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
                }
            },

Comment: I'm just going to show you the try{}, otherwise the whole function with form fields and catch is too long. You can see I call this.loadEmployerProfile(); before the $router.push.
createEmployerProfile: async function() {

                try {
                    const response = await employerProfileService.createProfile(formData);

                    this.loadEmployerProfile();
                    this.$router.push('/employer/profile');
                    this.$toast.success("Profile created Successfully!");

                }

Comment: You pass data down to child component via props and pass up via event.

Comment: Can I pass down an array using Props? If yes, then thank you for your responses. Wish me luck!